# jQuery, javascript, and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, simple:

```
self = $(this);
```

Throws a JavaScript error in IE8 when it's inside an event handler. It works in every other browser.

```
var self = $(this);
```

Throws no error. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is that `var` keyword staring back out at you.

When you reference just plain `self`, you're referencing a global variable and IE won't let you change it. When you write `var self` you're declaring a local variable.

Comment: Is 'self' a reserved word in IE8, or is IE8 just weirder than every other browser regarding global JavaScript variables?

Comment: It's not a reserved word, exactly, but it's a property of the `window` object that IE won't let you alter.