# calling one function from another in backbone view Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

What I want is to call plotPort from plotLoc using this.plotPort(); but I am unable to... but if I use self.plotPort(); it does not work for IE.
My workaround was to add event to lLoca upon reset to call plotPort. 
Why does not this.plotPort work?

```
var Loca = Backbone.Model.extend({latitude:{},longitude:{}});
        var LocaList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model : Loca,
            url : "/getLatLongList"
        });
        var PortList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model : Loca,
            url : "/getLatLongListForPort"
        });
        var lLoca = new LocaList;
        var lPort = new PortList;

        var CreateMap = Backbone.View.extend({

                    el : 'div',
                    map : {},
                    latitude : {},
                    longitude : {},             
                    initialize : function() {

                         var lOptions = {};                  
                    lOptions.success = this.plotLoc;
                        lLoca.fetch(lOptions,this);
                        lLoca.on('reset',this.plotPort(),this);
                        //_.bindAll(this,'plotPort');
                    },

                    plotLoc : function() {
                        // var test =lLoca.toJSON();
                        // $('#pchart').html(JSON.stringify(lLoca));

                        this.latitude = lLoca.toJSON()[0].latitude;
                        this.longitude = lLoca.toJSON()[0].longitude;
                        this.latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.latitude,
                                this.longitude);
                        var mapOptions = {
                            center : this.latlng,
                            zoom : 15,
                            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                            mapTypeControl : false,
                            streetViewControl : false,
                            navigationControlOptions : {
                                style : google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                            }
                        };
                        mapContainer = $("#mapContainer").get(0);
                        this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapContainer, mapOptions);

                        _.each(lLoca.models, function(loc) {
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position : new google.maps.LatLng(
                                        loc.toJSON().latitude,
                                        loc.toJSON().longitude),
                                map : this.map,
                                title : ""
                            });

                        }, this);
                        lLoca.reset();
                        //console.log(self+"");
                    //this.plotPort();
                    },
                    plotPort : function() {

                         lPort.fetch({                  
                         success: function() {
                             var postImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                                        "Images/greenflag.png",
                                        new google.maps.Size(50, 50));
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position : new google.maps.LatLng(
                                            lPort.toJSON()[0].latitude,
                                            lPort.toJSON()[0].longitude),
                                    map : this.map,
                                    icon : postImage,
                                    title : "From"

                                });
                                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position : new google.maps.LatLng(
                                            lPort.toJSON()[1].latitude,
                                            lPort.toJSON()[1].longitude),
                                    map : this.map,
                                    icon : postImage,
                                    title : "To"

                                });
                         }
                         });                        
                    },
                    render : function() {
                        return this;
                    }

                });
        var App = new CreateMap;
```

Answer (score 2):

What I can understand from your code, you should bind `reset` before doing `fetch` and also the binding is not proper it should be like this,

```
lLoca.on('reset', this.plotPort, this); // notice () being removed after this.plotPort
lLoca.fetch(lOptions, this);
```

This will bind the `reset` with the method instead of calling it.

And about calling one method from another its pretty straight forward, we just call it using `this`, but if that call is being made from some callback function or any other similar thing where `this` does not refer to the view, then its advised to save the reference of `this` before that callback and use it whenever required in the callback. For example,

```
var _view = this;
// doing collection fetch

this.collection.fetch({
  success :  function (collection, response) {
    // if you want to access view here, it can be accessed using 
    // '_view' variable, because 'this' here does not point to the view.
  }
});
```

This is just an example, but same concept can be used for similar problems.

Comment: its a simple reference variable, it should work, try giving it some different name, like `var $this = this` and use `$this`.

May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970263/jquery-javascript-and-ie8) is the reason.

Comment: Thanks and do you know a good tutorial which can help in development keeping in mind IE 8

Comment: Welcome :)

No CognitiveDesire, unfortunately I've no idea about any tutorial like it :(

Answer (score 0):

I would adwise to use `_.bindAll(this)` at the beginning of initialize function.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your initialize function

```
      _.bindAll(this,'plotPort', 'plotLoc');

      var lOptions = {};                  
      lOptions.success = this.plotLoc;
      lLoca.fetch(lOptions,this);
      lLoca.on('reset', this.plotPort, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

inside an object , from one function calling another function, you could use jQuery proxy to pass in the correct "this"

instead of

```
    this.plotPort();
```

try

```
    $.proxy(function () { 
        this.plotPort(); 
    }, this);
```